# swift Realm in background thread then app is crash

Tags: swift, background, realm

It seems! I have tried everything but I cant able to do.

I am getting data from database in every 2 mint and post data in API.And my app stuck for some sec in every 2 mint. The reason is when I am getting data from the database that time app is stuck. I have to do in the background.

This is my code is working but the app is Stuck

```
 func getObjects(type: Object.Type) -> Results<Object>? {

            //... *****************************
            //...code is working but app is stuck 

            return realm.objects(type)
        }

 if let list = realm.getObjects(type: AssignedCalendars.self)?.filter("isRemove == \(true) AND isSynced == \(false)").toArray(ofType: AssignedCalendars.self) {
                if list.count > 0 {
                    list.forEach({ (calendar) in
                        let calendar_json = [APIKey.event_id : calendar.event_id, APIKey.offlineId: calendar.offlineId, APIKey.calendar_id: calendar.calendar_id.toArray(ofType: Int.self)] as [String: Any]
                        removedCalendars.append(calendar_json)
                    })
                }
                offlineRemovedCalendars.append(contentsOf: list)
                eventData[APIKey.calendar_removelist] = removedCalendars
            }
```

TRY 1 . TRY for  run code in the background I have to try to use dispatch queue

```
func getObjects(type: Object.Type) -> Results<Object>? {

            //... *****************************
            //...code is working but app is stuck 

            return realm.objects(type)
        }


 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if let list = realm.getObjects(type: AssignedCalendars.self)?.filter("isRemove == \(true) AND isSynced == \(false)").toArray(ofType: AssignedCalendars.self) {

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if list.count > 0 {
                list.forEach({ (calendar) in
                    let calendar_json = [APIKey.event_id : calendar.event_id, APIKey.offlineId: calendar.offlineId, APIKey.calendar_id: calendar.calendar_id.toArray(ofType: Int.self)] as [String: Any]
                    removedCalendars.append(calendar_json)
                })
            }
            offlineRemovedCalendars.append(contentsOf: list)
            eventData[APIKey.calendar_removelist] = removedCalendars

          } //.. end bac que
        }
        })//... main que
```

TRY 2. use realm in background But i dont know how to use this method

```
extension Realm {



    func writeAsync<T : ThreadConfined>(obj: T, errorHandler: @escaping ((_ error : Swift.Error) -> Void) = { _ in return }, block: @escaping ((Realm, T?) -> Void)) {
        let wrappedObj = ThreadSafeReference(to: obj)
        let config = self.configuration
        DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
            autoreleasepool {
                do {
                    let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
                    let obj = realm.resolve(wrappedObj)

                    try realm.write {
                        block(realm, obj)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    errorHandler(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TRY 3. Found one solution but it's not working. it's not executed in a good way. IT's ADD Method, not a get

```
var usersRef: ThreadSafeReference<Results<User>>?
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    autoreleasepool{
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(users)
        }
        usersRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: users)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY 1 does't work because you can't pass a `Realm` object reference between threads. What you have to do:

```
var realmConig: Realm.Configuration = // your config - store it globally

// Now fetch the data
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    // Define a new Realm object inside async thread
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: realmConfig)
    // now fetch your objects
    let objects = realm.objects(Object.self)
    // From here you can perform actions with the objects
    // i.e. transform if to json format and submit via API
}
```

**Be warned**: In order to use `objects` outside of the background thread, you must transform them into array of `ThreadSafeReference` first. But it's not needed for your particular case, as far as I understood your goals.